# ViewController offset by 20 points when In-Call/Navigation Status Bar is dismissed

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nslayoutconstraint, uistatusbar

I'm not sure how to fix this and I've looked through quite a few answers on StackOverflow talking about resizing mask.

My top bar is a UIView that looks like a NavigationBar because I have animations that made it a lot easier to simulate a UINavigationBar than using it.

This UIViewController is embedded in a UINavigationController. The UIView that looks like a NavBar has a height of 64 points and has a constraint to its superview on the top of 0.

Here is a video of the issue.

[Video of issue](https://streamable.com/zvao1)